# Use of %d inside printf to print float value gives unexpected output

Tags: c, types, casting, int

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h.>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float f=11.11;
    printf("%d",f);
}
```

When i execute the following code in dev c++ it gives the output -536870912.
When i execute the same code on online tutorials point compiler i get different on every run. What could be the reason behind?

Comment: Note: You are compiling using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.

Answer (score 3):

If the argument doesn't match the format specifier, it's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Ue `%f` to print a float.

```
printf("%f",f);
```

You should be able to catch these sort of errors easily with good compilers. GCC produces:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
```

for your code.

P.S.: There's a stray dot in your `stdio.h` header inclusion.

Comment: `f` in fact expects a `double` not a `float` since C99 at least.

Comment: indeed but printf automatically promote to double

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you're asking *Why did it not print 11?* or *Why did it print different answers under different compilers?*.

The reason it didn't print 11 is that, as other answers have explained, `%d` doesn't print floats, and in `printf` calls there are no automatic conversions to fix up mismatches between passed and expected types.

And the reason it printed different things under different compilers is that it's *undefined behavior*, meaning anything can happen.  Suppose you go out to your car, loosen all the lugnuts on the front wheel until it's about to fall off, get in, and drive down the road at high speed until the wheel *does* fall off, whereupon you lose control and crash into a ditch.  And suppose you get a new car and do exactly the same thing tomorrow, except that by chance you crash into a tree instead.  At this point there are two approaches you could take:

1. Try to figure out what subtle factors caused you to crash into a ditch on one day, and a tree on another day.  Why wasn't it more repeatable?
2. Resolve not to try foolish experiments like this again.

Comment: @harishbisht29 Because `%c` is *defined* as accepting an `int`.  Also because there are some automatic conversions that do happen to the arguments when you call `printf`: `char` and `short` are promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`.  These are called the *usual argument promotions* or something like that, and they apply for any function that (like `printf`) accepts a variable number of arguments, and so has no fixed prototype.

Answer (score 1):

It's a float, use

```
printf("%f" , f);
```

If you don't it's an undefined behaviour.
To understand you can try to cast a int with value -1 to an unsigned int.

You will get an huge value.

Comment: `f` in fact expects a `double` not a `float` since C99 at least.

Comment: @alk Since values and variables smaller than `double` is promoted to `double` for varargs arguments it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Although it may produce unexpected behavior, casting a negative signed integer to an unsigned integer is not UB.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the conversion specifier and the type of the variable here:

```
  printf("%d",f);
```

Passing to `printf` other parameter(s) then specified by the conversion specifier(s) given by the format string provokes undefined behaviour. From that moment on everything can happen.

To fix this use the correct conversion specifier(s).

For floating point variables use the conversion specifier `f`, which expects a `double`. However when a `float` is passed to a variadic function like `printf` the `float` gets promote to a `double`.